# DeepClone(false) missing documentation

Tags: clone

I have class (v API 24) that clones a list of SObjects by calling `deepClone(false)` 
Can someone explain what the parameter means and how comes it is working if it doesn't appear on the list of supported operations.
I can upgrade the file to v39 without errors on save

Answer (score 3):

While the easily accessible online documentation doesn't go back as far as API 24, it would be a fairly safe bet that the behaviour is consistent with the current  [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm?search_text=deepClone) meaning `deepClone(false)` clears the ID value in the cloned SObjects of the cloned list:

> deepClone(preserveId, preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber)
>
> Makes a duplicate copy of a list of sObject records, including the
>   sObject records themselves. Signature
>
> public List deepClone(Boolean preserveId, Boolean
>   preserveReadonlyTimestamps, Boolean preserveAutonumber)
>
> Parameters
>
> preserveId
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> The **optional** preserveId argument determines whether the IDs of the
>   original objects are preserved or cleared in the duplicates. If set to
>   true, the IDs are copied to the cloned objects. The **default is false,
>   that is, the IDs are cleared**.
>
> preserveReadonlyTimestamps
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> The **optional** preserveReadonlyTimestamps argument determines whether
>   the read-only timestamp and user ID fields are preserved or cleared in
>   the duplicates. If set to true, the read-only fields CreatedById,
>   CreatedDate, LastModifiedById, and LastModifiedDate are copied to the
>   cloned objects. The **default is false, that is, the values are cleared**.
>
> preserveAutonumber
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> The **optional** preserveAutonumber argument determines whether the
>   autonumber fields of the original objects are preserved or cleared in
>   the duplicates. If set to true, auto number fields are copied to the
>   cloned objects. The **default is false, that is, auto number fields are
>   cleared**.